# Is the notion of set different from a notion of collection of objects?

Tags: group-theory, logic, set-theory

Based on this [answer](https://qr.ae/pNAmYm) on Quora, group theory doesn't need set theory to be formulated. But isn't it hardwired into the definition of a group that a group is an ordered pair $(G,\; \cdot\;)$, where G is a **set**. Furthermore, to even define binary operations, would we not need the notion of sets, since functions are a map from a set to another set.

Is it because the term "set" used in the definition of a group is just in the sense of "a collection of objects", rather than a set in ZFC.

Comment: In short, collection is an informal notion. You can formalise it in different ways. But it is most simply formalised using sets in ZFC, there are some issues with that since not every collection forms a set, but for practical purposes, set theory allows us to make enough collections into sets so that for most of mathematics, we don't know the difference.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So when we say $G$ is a set, do we really mean it's a collection?

Comment: What did you think it meant, when we say that something is a set?

Comment: @AsafKaragila A set as defined by ZFC

Comment: And that means... what?